# WPF-Popup Slide-Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popupwindow

I have a WPF C# Applikation with a xaml design. Here I use a button with a popup menu like the following:

```
<Button Name="btn" MouseEnter="ExtendPopup" />
<Popup Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}" PopupAnimation="Slide" MouseLeave="ClosePopup" >
    <StackPanel>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Can I change the "opening speed" and - even more important - can I change the opening direction?
The default is a `slide` opening from the top, but I want it from left.

Answer (score 0):

> The default is a slide opening from the top, but I want it from left.

You will need to either modify its style (using Blend is a good option) or create your own popup which slides in.

---

I discuss how to make a slide in control on my blog [WPF – Panel Slide-In Animation From Left Or Right Side](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1315) which if nothing else can show you how to adjust the style and datatriggers for the `Popup` control.

Comment: Your link is offline, but Wayback Machine works: https://web.archive.org/web/20230401210010/http://omegacoder.com/?p=1315